# Evidence shloka that time and material energy are eternal?

Tags: reference-request

To discuss with scientist, I have to prove that time and material energy, Maya, are eternal or no  beginning  and end by reference shloka . Someone pandit, could you help me, please.

Answer (score 3):

Hare Krishna

Here's reference from Bhagavad Gita which say material nature is beginningless:

> Material nature and the living entities should be understood to be beginningless. Their transformations and the modes of matter are products of material nature.

Source: https://asitis.com/13/20.html

Here's reference from Srimad Bhagavatam about eternal time:

> The Lord, who is the controller of all energies, thus creates, by His own potency, eternal time, the fate of all living entities, and their particular nature, for which they were created, and He again merges them independently.

Source: https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/2/5/21

Here's some research paper related to Bhagavad Gita which may appreciated by scientists:

**A randomized control trial of the effect of yoga on Gunas (personality) and Self esteem in normal healthy volunteers**

Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3017961/

**HEALTH DIMENSIONS OF GITA**

Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3331566/

Comment: Hare Krishna(^o^) PAMHO.AGTSP. Thank you,prabhu. Yes, they are nice silokas. But I knew them. I'm expecting evidence silokas from Upanishads, and from third person.  For their atheistic qualities they don't accept the existence of GOD, and what Sri Krsna directly says. As physics topics, we are discussing  the origin of the universe and theory of relativity. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hare Krsna(^o^) thank you for your concern,prabhu.  We, the scientists and me, are disccussion the material energy and time "as pure physics", without the existence of GOD. But if I can provide the reasonable explanations to them from Veda, they will accpt Veda.

Comment: Hare Krishna  According to quantum field theory and research, everything is field like electron field, photon field etc. Name like electron, quarks etc are given but really all physical nature is field and observer who measure or observe field as accepted by scientists who has studied quantum mechanics. Bhagavad Gita: "O chief of the Bharatas, whatever you see in existence, both moving and unmoving, is only the combination of the field of activities and the knower of the field."

Comment: Hare Krsna(^o^) prabhu, Thank you for sharing the scientific knowldge. But I do not accept the quantum physics. In the Veda the smallest unit is paramāṇu,atom.

Comment: Hare Krishna  There should be no contradiction. What Vedic literature refer by paramanu is not same as those refer by modern science. Modern science has given name atom first when they don't know what they say atom is divisible, but what refer by paramanu means it is already smallest part, and there is no mention that it must be particle as understood commonly. So, what refer by Vedic scriptures should be what is actually there ontologically as Gita describes reality as it is and science somewhat try to model reality and also comes to same conclusion that all nature is field.

Comment: Bhagavad Gita also described in 13.27 that "O chief of the Bharatas, whatever you see in existence, both moving and unmoving, is only the combination of the field of activities and the knower of the field." source: https://asitis.com/13/27.html   which is actually what reality as exactly describes by Supreme Lord Krishna.

Comment: Hare Krsna, "All the universes exist in Him and He is present in His fullness in every one of the atoms that are scattered throughout the universe, at one and the same time."  BS 5.35 The atom is the fundamental elements which cause the character of matter.